# What exactly does save/save! do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed that a common error check line in rails is:

```
if @user.save!
```

rather than something like

```
Save
If Save is successful
 Blah
Else
 Blah
End
```

So my understanding of "if @user.save!" is that it both saves the object and returns true/false if it was successful.  If I call it later on, such as:

```
@user.save!
if @user.save!
  blah
end
```

Am I executing the save query twice?

Comment: logically the answer would have to be "Yes", but I'm no Rails expert

Comment: Not sure, you may find that the second save doesn't bother to hit the database if nothing has changed in the object.  Be sure by checking out whether anything goes into the log file (logs/development.log in the development environment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little difference, I admit, but nevertheless, important. The documentation is quite good here:

save!

> With save! validations always run. If any of them fail ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid gets      raised.

save(perform_validation=true)

> if perform_validation is true validations run. If any of them fail the action is cancelled and save returns false. If the flag is false validations are bypassed altogether. See ActiveRecord::Validations for more information.

So, `save!` won't just return true or false but only true on success and raise an excpetion if it fails.

The purpose of this distinction is that with `save!`, you are able to catch errors in your controller using the standard ruby facilities for doing so, while `save` enables you to do the same using standard if-clauses.

Comment: Thanks Moritz.  One question from above though, given my last example of saving, then using "if save!"... is it hitting the db twice?

Comment: hm, from my understanding, an orm layer like AR is also optimizing stuff, and sending an unmodified object to database for (re)saving is.. not that clever, so my guess would be no :-)